# iOS iPad App flags are very slow

Tags: bug, ios-app, ipad

When I tap to flag the answer or question in ios app on iPad flag reasons loading near 20-30 seconds. 
Also there is no any success info message like on site after flag reason was selected and the request was sended to server.

Comment: I think its safe to say 6-8 seconds.

Comment: It is slow on an iPhone 5 as well, but definitely not 20-30 seconds.

Comment: It takes about 10 seconds for me.